# Regular Expression for multiple numbers at the end of an expression

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression that will break up strings with numbers at the end. Currently I am able to do this with one number at the end using:

```
(\w+)(\d+)
```

This will break up something like abc0 into "abc" and "0." Unfortunately, this does not seem to work with something like abc01. I recieve "abc0" and "1."

I also tried:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)
```

This did work for that case, but I would like something like a1bc01 to be broken up into "a1bc" and "01."

Comment: What language and how do you apply the regex?

Comment: (\w+?)(\d+), I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non greedy regex operator and use `\b` to help your match with digits at the end:

```
(\w+?)(\d+)\b
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xUmwD2/1)**